# Добавление тега script в React JS

Tags: html, reactjs

Мне нужно добавить виджет ПВЗ СДЭК(Карта с пунктами выдачи) в react приложение. В документации сдэка про библиотеки для react'a ничего нет, есть так код HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Пример работы виджета ПВЗ</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/widjet.js" id="ISDEKscript" ></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    var widjet = new ISDEKWidjet({
        defaultCity: 'Уфа',
        cityFrom: 'Омск',
        link: 'forpvz',
        path: 'https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/scripts/',
        servicepath: 'https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/scripts/service.php'
    });
</script>


<p>Пример минимальной установки виджета</p>
<div id="forpvz" style="height:600px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Скрипт в теге head я могу просто добавить в index.html react приложения

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/widjet.js" id="ISDEKscript" ></script>
```

Скрипт

```
<script>
var widjet = new ISDEKWidjet({
    defaultCity: 'Уфа',
    cityFrom: 'Омск',
    link: 'forpvz',
    path: 'https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/scripts/',
    servicepath: 'https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/scripts/service.php'
});
</script>
```

мне нужно добавить в компоненту чтобы взаимодействовать с полями defaultCity и cityFrom, как его переместить в компоненту чтобы всё работало? Блок div будет в этой же компоненте.

Comment: Пробовали эту строчку `var widjet = new ISDEKWidjet` пихнуть в ф-ию рендер (если пишите классами) или перед `return` (если пишите ф-иями)?

Answer (score 0):

Работает, если вписать в компоненту. Единнственное там ошибка в скрипте виджета, не стал с этим разбираться

Код:

```js
const App = () => {
  const widjet = new ISDEKWidjet({
    defaultCity: 'Уфа',
    cityFrom: 'Омск',
    link: 'forpvz',
    path: 'https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/scripts/',
    servicepath: 'https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/scripts/service.php'
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <p>Пример минимальной установки виджета</p>
      <div id="forpvz" style={{height: '600px'}}></div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://widget.cdek.ru/widget/widjet.js" id="ISDEKscript"></script>
```

Comment: У меня App тоже стрелочная функция, мне выводит ошибку 'ISDEKWidjet' is not defined

Comment: @Jakalgit А вы скрипт в `head`-е подклюсили?

Comment: widjet я написал так же как и у вас в App, а скрипт да - в head